How to set providers in Angular v19 SSR?
In Angular <19
I used such code to specify the providers:
  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('**', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: distFolder,
        providers: [
          { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
          { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res },
          { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req },
        ],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });

but in Angular 19 there is another structure:
app.use('/**', (req, res, next) => {
  angularApp
    .handle(req)
    .then((response) =>
      response ? writeResponseToNodeResponse(response, res) : next(),
    )
    .catch(next);
});

I have tried to add the providers array in the second parameter of handle() method, but it did not work for me.
I need to set providers for the REQUEST token, which should be the req object

In v19 those token are set for you automatically by the framework.
In your app, you'll pull them from '@angular/core'
import { Component, inject REQUEST, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    const request = inject(REQUEST, { optional: true });
  }
}

Make sure to inject is with optional: true as this token will not be available in every context.
I have a working demo you can check: https://github.com/jeanmeche/ssr-v19

I cannot get why I don't have tokens directory in the @angular/ssr. I tried to install the same version like you have, but still the tokens are missing

Oh you're right, the have been moved to @angular/core. I've updated the demo & the answser.

const injectedRequest = inject(REQUEST);     console.log({ REQUEST, injectedRequest }); outputs [ng] { [ng]   REQUEST: <ref *1> InjectionToken { [ng]     _desc: 'REQUEST', [ng]     ngMetadataName: 'InjectionToken', [ng]     'ɵprov': { [ng]       token: [Circular *1], [ng]       providedIn: 'platform', [ng]       factory: [Function: factory], [ng]       value: undefined [ng]     } [ng]   }, [ng]   injectedRequest: null [ng] }
I see that the token exists, but when I inject it - I don't have a value, it is null.

I have added , { optional: true } but it did not change anything. The inject(REQUEST) is null for the server context.

btw, in your demo project you should replace .render() with .handle() in four server files.

Finally I have found the problem. The issue lies here: provideServerRoutesConfig(serverRoutes),
If it is removed - the tokens are null, otherwise the REQUEST is available on the server context

Additional note : If you want to inject custom tokens from your node server and provide them to your angular v19 app, you can use REQUEST_CONTEXT from @angular/core.
server.ts
app.use('/**', (req, res, next) => {
  angularApp
    .handle(req, {
      context: { foo: 'bar' },
    })
    .then((response) =>
      response ? writeResponseToNodeResponse(response, res) : next(),
    )
    .catch(next);
}); 

Then use TransferState API to get your data in the browser.
const CONTEXT_KEY = makeStateKey<any>('context');

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ServerContextService {
  constructor(
  ) {
    const transferState = inject(TransferState);
    const CONTEXT_TOKEN:any = inject(REQUEST_CONTEXT, { optional: true });

    if(CONTEXT_TOKEN) {
      transferState.set(CONTEXT_KEY, CONTEXT_TOKEN);
    }

    this.transfered = transferState.get(CONTEXT_KEY, {});
  }

  transfered: any;
}


make sure to use option:true for the context: inject(REQUEST_CONTEXT);
